# How to build a flat groupbox in PyQt5?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qgroupbox

I found the flat property of the QGroupbox Class in the [Qt-docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#flat-prop), where it says:

> A group box usually consists of a surrounding frame with a title at the top. If this property is enabled, only the top part of the frame is drawn in most styles; otherwise, the whole frame is drawn.

I'm trying to build such a flat QGroupBox, but it doesn't seem to work, as you can see in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Zq7.png). In the docs it also says:

> **Note:** In some styles, flat and non-flat group boxes have similar representations and may not be as distinguishable as they are in other styles.

That leads me to the [QStyle Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html), which overstrains me a little, as I have no idea how to change the Style of the QGroupBox. I'm not even sure, if this is the real problem here. As you can see in my code below, I don't assign a specific style to the QGroupBox. So, it should use some sort of standard style, i guess...

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGroupBox, 
QVBoxLayout, QLabel


class WidgetWithFlatGroupBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self, flags=Qt.Widget)

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Window')

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.create_groupbox(), alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def create_groupbox(self):
        groupbox = QGroupBox('Flat Groupbox')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        label = QLabel('This Groupbox should be flat.')

        layout.addWidget(label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        groupbox.setLayout(layout)

        groupbox.setFlat(True)

        return groupbox


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = WidgetWithFlatGroupBox()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I had a look at the internet, also here at stackoverflow of course, but were not able to find something useful. Is there anyone who knows how to use the flat property of the QGroupBox Class properly?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I do not understand how you need to do:

- `border: None;`

[image]

- `border: 1px solid #76797C;`

[image]

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QGroupBox, 
                             QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton)


class WidgetWithFlatGroupBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self, flags=Qt.Widget)

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Window')

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.create_groupbox(), alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def create_groupbox(self):
        groupbox = QGroupBox('Flat Groupbox')

        layout   = QVBoxLayout()

        label = QLabel('This Groupbox should be flat.')

        button = QPushButton("This Button !!!")
        button.setFlat(True)

        layout.addWidget(label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        groupbox.setLayout(layout)
#        groupbox.setFlat(True)

        return groupbox

style = '''
QGroupBox {

    border: None;               /*<-----  None              */
/*    border: 1px solid #76797C;   <-----  1px solid #76797C */

    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: top center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(style)

    ex = WidgetWithFlatGroupBox()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This may not be what I was looking for in the first place, but yet somehow helpful. I found out, it actually is about the Style used. With `app.setStyle('Windows')` the flat property is set properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
self.groupBox_33.setFlat(True)
```

Comment: Please explain how this is different than `groupbox.setFlat(True)` in the question.